# Links very slow to display 'large' components

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am working on a React app, and within it there is a page with a lot of graphs and large list component, which takes some time to load (performance dependant). This is fine for now, but the issue comes from the following:

- at the first render, there is an API call (App wide as different pages use the same data). A loading spinner shows while the API data is fetched
- Once the data is fetched, it is Redux manages the state, and each component just takes what it needs from there (no more loading).

My issue is that when I navigate between pages trough links (react-router), after I click on the link it takes a while for the page to show and the menu to update the current page. None of the state data has changed in that timeframe, so I assumed a PureComponent would prevent re-render, but it doesn't work.

Is there any way to not re-render the page? I would expect to click on a link an immediately see the page that was already loaded before.

Sorry if the question is obvious, I got quite confused while researching this, with cold splitting, lazy loading, etc. which seems to be more about initial load vs. navigation?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large component dataset to mount and your state does not changes or affects re-renders you could prevent component from unmounting entirely.

If you are using react-router you can rely on `setRouteLeaveHook`.
If your unmount depends on conditional rendering, it is easier as you can hide your component in various way, including css `display:none`

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can do this

The first one would be to not unmount the component, just hide it with CSS and `display: none`, but that's a shit solution if you ask me, since you'll still have the component in the DOM.

Another solution that you can use is the one that the guys from the Facebook team used when creating the official website for React. Once you hover over the link to the page, send a request to prefetch the data for that page. So, before the user even clicked, you will have the request already sent.

Another solution you can use is to cache the data. If you are not worried about users with older browsers waiting a bit for the component to load again. You can keep the data for the component in `localStorage`, then, when you are about to mount the component, check if the data is already in localStorage if it's there, just render the component, if not, just grab the data again.

A combination of the first and the second option would make your component pretty much always instantly render.

Comment: Hi Bojan, thanks! When you say pre-fetch, do you mean access it from redux? The data is fetched once when the page is loaded and the state is managed by redux. I wouldn't want to fetch new data everytime the link is clicked (it is unlikely to change for some time). The issue seems to be that rendering the list (through .map() ) and some graphs take time to render on screen and the link doesn't change until this has happened.